# What is the proper Resource value in AWS Step Function SendTaskSuccess task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am creating an async task using AWS Step Functions. I created a Step Function calling another Step Function with .waitForTaskToken and stored Task Token in DB.
Now I'm creating another Step Function that processes a message from API Gateway and calls SendTaskSuccess. Here is the exact state, the Workflow Studio generated for me:

```
    "SendTaskSuccess": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "End": true,
      "Parameters": {
        "output": "{}",
        "taskToken.$": "$.taskToken"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:states:sendTaskSuccess"
    },
```

My problem is that when I'm saving the Step Function, it tells me this:

```
There are Amazon States Language errors in your state machine definition. Fix the errors to continue.
The resource provided arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:states:sendTaskSuccess is not recognized. The value is not a valid resource ARN, or the resource is not available in this region.
For more information, see Amazon States Language
```

So my question is - what would be the proper Resource value for this task? In the Workflow Studio, there is no way to specify any resource to use, it generates the ARN above automatically

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and it appears
`arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sfn:sendTaskSuccess` (`sfn` instead of `states`) is the correct arn.
Furthermore, the parameters should start with an uppercase letter:

```
"Parameters": {
  "TaskToken.$": "$.taskToken",
  "Output.$": "$.outputs"
}
```

I also checked the Workflow Studio, which produced the above arn in my case.

Comment: For everyone having issues setting the permissions up via CDK (CallAwsService), use the `iamAction` field like: `{ service: 'sfn', action: 'sendTaskSuccess', iamAction: 'states:SendTaskSuccess', ... }`